# mysql limit rows returned for each group

Tags: mysql

i have this result in a table

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|adm_no   |   code     | value   |   group_id    |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  101       | 50      |    1          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |   102      | 60      |    1          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  121       | 62      |    1          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  233       |  50     |   2           |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  231       |  98     |   2           |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  232       | 85      |    2          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     | 511        |   75    |     3         |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  585       |   38    |     3         |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |  711       |    45   |      4        |
+------------------------------------------------+
|1200     |   785      |     45  |      4        |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

now i can select a limited set of rows for each group as long as the number to limit is the same but i dont know how to do this.

so what i want to do is this:

1.select all rows that have group_id=1

2.select only the first two rows that have group_id=2

3.select only the first row that have group_id=3 and group_id=4

any pointers possibly if it can be done in a single query

Comment: yes, use variables, help will be on the way shortly from someone. So that means if the likes of Gordon are around, who can type 300 wpm, you will get an answer pronto :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT adm_no, code, value, group_id
FROM (
  SELECT adm_no, code, value, group_id,
         @rn := IF (@gr = group_id,
                    IF(@gr := group_id, @rn+1, @rn+1),
                    IF(@gr := group_id, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @gr:=0) AS vars
  ORDER BY group_id, code ) t
WHERE (group_id = 1) 
      OR (group_id = 2 AND rn <= 2) 
      OR (group_id IN (3,4) AND rn = 1)
```

Variables `@rn`, `@gr` are used to implement `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ..)` window function available in other RDBMSs like SQL SERVER, PostgreSQL, etc...

So, `@rn` essentially is used to enumerate records within each `group_id` slice. Using this variable in an outer query we can easily get the expected result set.

Please note the use of *nested conditionals*, in order to properly consume and *then* set `@gr` variable.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56787b/3)